# integer wrap-around not really understood

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code which is called **approximately** 100 times per second

```
if (elapsed_centiseconds_mod_60000 < 59999) {
    ++elapsed_centiseconds_mod_60000;
} else {
    elapsed_centiseconds_mod_60000 = 0;
}
if (elapsed_centiseconds_mod_60000 % 6000 == 0) {
    ++elapsed_minutes;
}
```

The types of the variables and constants are

```
volatile uint16_t elapsed_centiseconds_mod_60000;
volatile uint8_t start_minute_mod_10;
const int8_t calibration_second = 5;
```

Then **exactly** once per second the following is called

```
int16_t get_phase_deviation(uint8_t current_second, uint8_t current_minute_mod_10) {
    int32_t deviation=
         (int32_t) elapsed_centiseconds_mod_60000 -
        ((int32_t) current_second        + (int32_t)600 - (int32_t)calibration_second) * (int32_t) 100 -
        ((int32_t) current_minute_mod_10 + (int32_t) 60 - (int32_t)start_minute_mod_10)* (int32_t)6000;
    deviation %= 60000;

    return (int16_t)(deviation<=30000? deviation: deviation-60000);
}
```

The idea of the code is to detect relative frequency error of two oscillators. However the code does not work as expected. It will start to output a deviation of zero. But once the elapsed centiseconds are one more than they should it will jump immediately to an output of 5537 which coincidences with 2^16 % 60000 + 1. I tried to cast the intermediate values to int32_t but still the issue sticks. Usually the issue appears after 100 seconds or 10 000 centiseconds. I suspect some wrap around issue but I fail to see it.

Has anyone any idea which term is causing this and why?

Comment: Is this code multi-threaded? You might need some guards to make sure a value isn't incrementing at exactly the same time you're trying to perform the calculation.

Comment: @NeilKirkI do not miss a 0 in the first block. It is 6000 centiseconds per minute. As soon as the elapsed_centiseconds are 0 mod 6000 I advance the minute.

Comment: @Mark Ransom With regard to the multi threading - the code is not multi threaded but interrupt driven. You are right to suspect that this code must be protected somehow, I removed this piece of code as I already verified that this is not causing the issue.

Comment: One more thing: this code is running in parallel with some well tested calibration method that advances exactly 1 step (as it should) exactly in the same period as this code outputs 5537. Thus I am very confident that I have no race conditions here. Repeating the experiment will give same results no matter when it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly casting the return value of `get_phase_deviation()` as the range of `deviation %= 60000` is `-59999 to 59999` (*not* `0 to 59999`). You should change the line:

```
 return (int16_t)(deviation<=30000? deviation: deviation-60000);
```

to correctly deal with deviation <= -30000 as is appropriate or change the return type to `int32_t`.

Looking at the specific cases to understand the numbers you were getting, assuming:

```
 calibration_second = 0;
 start_minute_mod_10 = 0;
```

Then for a perfect system `get_phase_deviation()` is returning:

```
 deviation = -420000; // As computed
 deviation %= 60000;  // == 0
 return 0;
```

If you are 1 centisecond ahead this changes to:

```
 deviation = -419999; // As computed
 deviation %= 60000;  // == -59999
 return (int16_t) (-59999);  // == 5537
```

Comment: As this is a microcontroller I am tight on memory. However you got me on the right track. I will replace the + (int32_t)600  by - (int32_t)600

Comment: @UdoKlein I don't know if that's going to help. It seems that you want the output to be in the -30000 to 30000 range, so the best strategy would be to put the result of the `%=` in the 0 to 60000 range: `if (deviation < 0) deviation += 60000;`